# Post New Job Positions for 2 Web Developers at the same time or post one now and another 3 months later?

Tags: software-industry, software-development, hiring, developer, web

We are planning on hiring 2 new developers. One front-end developer and one-backed developer. We currently have a team of about 7 developers so this would bring us up to 9. We are trying to push management to hire both at the same time so we can get them up to speed right away and get them working on projects. Their push-back is that hiring 2 at the same time will slow down productively to much at the beginning.

My feeling is more of a rip of the band-aid type of approach, lets get them in, productively will likely slow for about a month but then should start to accelerate. I need to come back with at least 3 major points on the benefits of hiring both at the same time, please respond if you agree with my solution of 2 developers and the main points, or if I'm wrong respond with why we shouldn't hire both at the same time?

Comment: I don't know about your job market situation, but for me this sounds like overthinking the issue. I wouldn't have someone *fitting* to hire right away and the availability of a fitting candidates would be much more a constraint than such considerations. Did you take that into account, i.e. do you have sufficient candidates available to micro-manage their joining date like this?

Comment: I agree with that, that's part of the reason why I believe we should post both jobs at the same time, if we get good candidates from both hire both, if we only get good candidates for 1 hire only the one job and maybe re-post later in the year. I've reworded my question to focus more on how many job posts to recreate rather then hire.

Comment: Given that the FE and BE devs have different skill sets, waiting to fill one job first (e.g. FE) will necessarily delay when you post the other, potentially missing out on qualified candidates for the second.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If both positions are open now, fill them now.

- You don't know how long it will take to fill each position.
- The sooner you hire, the sooner the ramp up period will be complete and the new devs can really contribute to your workload.
- Where there are common ramp-up, you can get a 2-for-1.  When you have something to show 1 dev, you can call the other over and show them at the same time. Will save you having to do it all again 3 months later.
- You will get less done while you are short handed.
- If they start at the same time, because they are both in the same boat as the new guy, they will have an immediate friend/ally.

Comment: Plus people tend to learn faster/easier when paired with other people who are learning the same stuff.